pyspark --files no such file or Directory error
I am getting "No such file or directory" error while using --files option in cluster mode.
Can someone please help if I am missing something.
your_file_name.txt [Sample Input File]
abc
xyz
pqr
cat script.py [Code File]
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark import SparkFiles
Create SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
Access the file using SparkFiles.get()
file_path = SparkFiles.get("your_file_name.txt")
Read the file content
with open(file_path, "r") as f:
content = f.read()
Do something with the content
print(content)
spark3-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --files your_file_name.txt script.py
=============================================================================================
LogType:stdout
LogLastModifiedTime:Wed Dec 04 10:47:07 +0000 2024
LogLength:355
LogContents:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "script.py", line 12, in 
with open(file_path, "r") as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/dfs/10/yarn/nm/usercache/dmahajan/appcache/application_1724863745359_15570/spark-86bec527-b8d8-4ece-b449-36da0910eca7/userFiles-2056673d-bcef-4300-803a-62a368d6a82c/your_file_name.txt'
End of LogType:stdout

